# Vuetify: v-dialog won't close although v-model variable is set to false

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a couple of dialogs which are created with v-for (`exchangeTypeAbbreviation` and `exchangeType` come from there). When I click on the activator button, the dialog opens and the value in the object I use for storing the dialogs' state is updated to "true".
But when I click the cancel or save button, the dialog won't close, although the object's value is updated to "false".

```html
<v-list-item>
  <v-dialog
    max-width="400"
    v-model="dialogs[exchangeTypeAbbreviation]"
  >
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-list-item v-on="on">
      <v-icon class="pr-4">
        mdi-plus
      </v-icon>
      Add Product Flow
    </v-list-item>
  </template>

  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>Add Product Flow</v-card-title>
    <v-card-subtitle
      v-text="exchangeType"
    ></v-card-subtitle>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        @click="
        dialogs[exchangeTypeAbbreviation] = false;
        createUnitProcessExchange(
            exchangeTypeAbbreviation
        );
        "
        >Save</v-btn
      >
      <v-btn
          @click="dialogs[exchangeTypeAbbreviation] = false"
          >Cancel</v-btn
      >
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</v-list-item>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Activities',

  data: () => ({
    dialogs: {},
    exchangeTypes: {},
    unitProcessExchangesOptions: null,
    }
  }),

  mounted() {
    Promise.all([
      this.loadUnitProcessExchangeOptions()
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    async loadUnitProcessExchangeOptions() {
      return this.$api
        .options('/unitprocessexchanges/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.unitProcessExchangesOptions = response.data.actions.POST
          for (const exchangeType of this.unitProcessExchangesOptions
            .exchange_type.choices) {
            this.exchangeTypes[exchangeType.value] = exchangeType.display_name
            this.dialogs[exchangeType.value] = false
          }
        })
    },

    async createUnitProcessExchange(exchangeTypeAbbreviation) {
      this.newUnitProcessExchange.activity = this.activities[
        this.selectedActivity
      ].url
      this.newUnitProcessExchange.exchange_type = exchangeTypeAbbreviation

      this.dialogs[exchangeTypeAbbreviation] = false
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
      debugger
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out why it doesn't work. Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue.js has some difficulties to observe changes in Objects and Arrays. This is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

In my case, I added nested variables inside my "dialogs" variable by assigning them directly, e.g. like this

```
this.dialogs[index] = false
```

However, this creates a sub-element which can't be tracked by Vue.js. To make sure that changes on this element can be tracked, it either has to be pre-defined from the beginning or needs to be set by using the `Vue.$set` command. Always using the following command, solved the issue for me:

```
this.$set(dialogs, index, false)
```

Comment: This helped me big time! Thanks so much.

Comment: Very late reply, but I'm happy that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is you are trying to change the object with an array notation i.e array[0] but it should be a dot notation with object property, in your case it would be dialogs.exchangeTypeAbbreviation = false.

With that one more problem would be that property doesn't exist so in

```
data: () => ({
dialogs: {exchangeTypeAbbreviation:Boolean},
exchangeTypes: {},
unitProcessExchangesOptions: null,
 }
}),
```

with this now you can set the value of exchangeTypeAbbreviation.

Comment: Hey, I guess it did not become clear, but there are multiple exchangeTypeAbbreviations. It's a list of multiple items, which is why I use array notation. You can see that the method which loads the unitProcessExchangeTypes, the corresponding subentries in `dialog` are added as "false".

As stated in the text, "exchangeType" and "exchangeTypeAbbreviations" come from the "v-if" that is not displayed in my code snippet above.

Comment: Also, the state of the variable is actually changed when the dialog is opened and also when I click the close button. But the dialog is not closed.